# Using ConTeXt, how do I keep paragraph breaks inside a layer inside a setups?

Tags: context

I'm attempting to create a letterhead that includes the recipient's name, the date, and the page in the margin of every page.

Here is my attempt:

```
\setupbodyfont[12pt]
\definelayer[restpagemargin]%
    [x=0.5in, y=1in, width=2in]

\startsetups restpagemargin 
\setlayerframed
        [restpagemargin]
        [hoffset=0cm, voffset=0cm, width=1.75in, align=flushleft, frame=off]%
        {%
            John Doe

            Today’s Date

            Page \rawcountervalue[userpage] of \lastcountervalue[userpage]%
        }
\stopsetups

\setupbackgrounds[page][background={restpagemargin},setups=restpagemargin]

\starttext

\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth
\input knuth


\stoptext
```

Although the text appears on the page, for some reason the paragraph breaks between the name, date, and page number disappear, ultimately being typeset on each page as `John DoeToday’s DatePage 4 of 4`.

How do I make sure the paragraph breaks appear in the output?

Comment: What happens if you explicitly write `\par` instead of using blank lines?

Comment: @HenriMenke  That worked! Do you know why \par works but the double carriage return doesn't?

Comment: The `setups` environment ignores line endings which is intended. To keep the line endings you can use the `rawsetups` environment or use ``\\`` to force a line break in the frame.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster Using `\startrawsetups` -- `stoprawsetups` also worked!

I don't know what the proper etiquette is, but I would be happy to accept either solution as resolving my question. If you'd rather, I can also write the solution myself using the information you've provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put your `layer` in a `setups` environment which ignores the line endings. This means no space are addded between words on different lines and a empty line in the input doesn't result in a new paragraph.

```
\starttext

\startsetups[nospace]
    No
    space!
\stopsetups

\setup[nospace]

\startsetups[noparagraphs]
    No

    paragraphs!
\stopsetups

\setup[noparagraphs]

\stoptext
```

[image]

To insert in a space or start a new paragraph in the example above you can use the `\space` or `\par` commands or in your case with `\framed` using `\\` is another option.

Another option is to use the `rawsetups` environment which doesn't ignore line endings and results in the expected output.

```
\starttext

\startsetups[framed:setups]
    \startframed[align=flushleft,width=5cm]
        First paragraph.

        Second paragraph.
    \stopframed
\stopsetups

\setup[framed:setups]

\startsetups[framed:backslash]
    \startframed[align=flushleft,width=5cm]
        First paragraph.\\
        Second paragraph.
    \stopframed
\stopsetups

\setup[framed:backslash]

\startsetups[framed:par]
    \startframed[align=flushleft,width=5cm]
        First paragraph.\par
        Second paragraph.
    \stopframed
\stopsetups

\setup[framed:par]

\startrawsetups[framed:rawsetups]
    \startframed[align=flushleft,width=5cm]
        First paragraph.

        Second paragraph.
    \stopframed
\stoprawsetups

\setup[framed:rawsetups]

\stoptext
```

[image]

This unexpected behaviour of the `setups` ennvironment is intended because it is often used to create apply a list of setups (in combination with conditionals) like the following two examples:

```
\startsetups[...]

    \setupXXX[..,..=..,..]

    \setupY[..,..=..,..]

\stopsetups

\startsetups[...]
    \doifelse{...}{...}
        {
            ...
        }
        {
            ...
        }
\stopsetups
```